# OnItemClickListener() in LazyList

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener, lazylist

I have used `Lazylist` from this [code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/), but I don't know how to implement `OnItemClickListener()`

I used this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id + "", 2000).show(); 
 });
```

But it's just get item position. I want to get array hashmap who include `KEY_ID`, `KEY_TITLE` and `KEY_ARTIST`, just like when we use `ListActivity`

Answer (score 0):

In LazyAdapter class override the method as follows:

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

now in

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
adater.getItem(position);
});
```